# Laravel form validation doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm making my first form in Laravel and the generation of the form is all working. It's just that the store function seems to blindly return the user to my contact page irrelevant of the result of the form validation.

So if the email address posted isn't an email but a random string I still get returned to the /contact page with the thank you message being sent to the view.

My controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

class ContactController extends Controller {

  public function create(){
      return view('contact');
  }

  public function store(ContactFormRequest  $request) {

      return \Redirect::route('contact')
        ->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');

  }
}
```

And the form handler like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactFormRequest extends Request {
  public function authorize() {
    return true;    // don't need to be registered to run form so true
  }
  public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];
  }
}
```

This is controlled by the following routes

```
if (config('app.tan_site_page_contact')===true){
    Route::get('/contact', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'ContactController@create']);
    Route::post('/contact', ['as' => 'contact_store', 'uses' => 'ContactController@store']);
});
```

And the form like this:

```
  <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
   @if(Session::has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{Session::get('message')}}
      </div>
   @endif


 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'contact_store', 'id' => 'contactCallMeForm')) !!}         
 {!! Form::label('Your E-mail Address') !!}
 {!! Form::text('email', null,  array('required',  'class'=>'form-control',  'placeholder'=>'Your e-mail address')) !!}
 {!! Form::submit('Contact Us!',  array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!} 
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The form html seems fine,with a token and valid url

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/contact" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="contactCallMeForm" novalidate="">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="VNHchLZhfsXadVZXCZWHGdAuJ4zgmO6cDJIGhR59">
    <label for="Your E-mail Address">Your E-mail Address</label>
    <input required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Your e-mail address" name="email" type="text">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Contact Us!">
</form>
```

Comment: Show HTML of generated form, also add routes.

Comment: Please add your declarations for `contact` and `contact_store` routes.

Comment: Now updated @Kyslik

Comment: @salamza updated for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `ContactFormRequest` class.

You extends it from invalid `Request` class. You extend it from `\Illuminate\Http\Request` class but you should extend it from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` (or `\App\Http\Requests\Request` class)

Comment: I get Class 'App\Http\Requests\Request' not found errors if I change this to either of those classes.  Do I need to add something to the app.php to set them up ?

Comment: @AdamJones If you don't have this class, just extend from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` class or you can create one - same as https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Requests/Request.php

Comment: Thank you @Marcin Nabiałek !  That link did the trick, I was extending "Request", not "FormRequest" !

Comment: Which method to use to validate in \App\Http\Requests\Request class?